# Django Rest angular2 http get

Tags: angular, django-rest-framework

Am using angular2 with django rest Api. Am trying to retrieve an account using http get in a service in the code bellow :

```
getAccountBackend(id: string) : Promise<any> { 
   const slash="/"
   const urlaccount = `${this.urlAccontBackend}${id}${slash}`;
   console.log('url du compte', urlaccount)
   return this.http.get(urlaccount)
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => {
         response.json().data
         console.log(response)}
      )
     .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

When try to resolve this method in the component :

```
getAccountById(){
  console.log("i will resolve the account");
  this.fcbAccSrv.getAccountBackend('1234896')
    .then(data=> {
      this.compte=data
      console.log("the account from the backend", this.compte);
   })
 .catch(error =>{ this.error = error;
   console.log('error to resolve account')});
}
```

I got a response with http ok but the account in the component is undefined : 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `return`, and your response doesn't seem to have `data`, so

```
.then(response => { response.json().data })
```

should be:

```
.then(response => { return response.json() })
```